# AudioRecord: start() status -38 in cordova android application only in Samsung s8 device

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins, android-audiomanager

I am building a video conferencing application in Cordova android based on webRTC. I am using a plugin **"phonegap-plugin-media-stream"** for getUserMedia. Audio is working on all devices except Samsung s8. However, using the Samsung S8, after mute/unmute audio 4 to 5 times it started to work.

When I check the android logs for Samsung S8 then I found the following.

```
D/AudioManager: setSpeakerphoneOn true
W/AudioManager: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2020-05-18 20:49:49.647 10826-10826/com.example.hello W/AudioManager: See the documentation of requestAudioFocus() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
D/AudioManager: requestAudioFocus status : 1
W/AudioManager: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
W/AudioManager: See the documentation of requestAudioFocus() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
D/AudioManager: requestAudioFocus status : 1
```

But in other mobiles, we are not getting the above error and audio works fine.